# Python assign parameters dinamically to Format function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a simple script to format data. I don't know how many elements I have to format because they came in a variable array.

I think I need to pass parameters dynamically to the Format function. Are there some way to drive this case?

```py
    def formatting(p_array):
        format_string = ''
        lin = ''
        for i in range(len(p_array)):
            format_string += '{:>20}'
            lin += "'"+p_array[i]+"'"
            if i < len(p_array)-1:
                lin += ","

        # Next line gives ERROR.
        print(format_string.format(lin))

    # c_attributes can have more o less elements.
    c_attributes = ['userAccountControl','cn', 'sAMAccountName', 'mail']
    formatting(c_attributes)
```

I receive the following error: "IndexError: tuple index out of range"

Answer (score 3):

You only need two lines of code:

```
format_string = '{:>20}'*len(p_array)
print(format_string.format(*p_array)
```

The first line builds up your `format_string` immediately, instead of looping over the elements of the input array. The second line correctly passes each element of that array to `format_string.format` as a separate argument, rather than passing a single *string* built from those elements.

You are trying to run `"...".format("x,y,z")` instead of `"...".format(x, y, z)`.